# How to make Hokusai bouncy action sheet Pod animate from top, not bottom

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cocoapods, cgrect

First off, I want to preface by saying i know this question has a VERY small scope, specific to one pod that many people may have never used or even heard about. BUT if anyone has ever run into the same issue as me, or would like to do a little digging and help me out, some insight would be greatly and truly appreciated.

[Hokusai](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Hokusai) is a Pod made by ytakzk that mirrors Skype's action sheet, bouncing up from the bottom of the page.

I have been looking over the code trying to make the necessary changes to get it to be pretty much the opposite when it comes to the y axis, bouncing down from the top and then receding back to the top when dismissed.

I am not familiar AT ALL with CGRects (currently learning!) so it is really difficult to even understand what to manipulate and where.

Thanks for reading, hopefully someone will be able to help me out, and it is one of the most popular pods, so if you do create a viable solution, i'm sure you will end up helping hundreds of others as well!

I feel like its somewhere within this method here, so I'm including it, although [This is a link to the .swift file on GitHub](https://github.com/ytakzk/Hokusai/blob/master/Classes/Hokusai.swift) if you think it may be something else.

```
func updatePath() {
    let width  = CGRectGetWidth(shapeLayer.bounds)
    let height = CGRectGetHeight(shapeLayer.bounds)

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    path.addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: width, y: 0),
        controlPoint:CGPoint(x: width * 0.5, y: 0 + bendableOffset.vertical))
    path.addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: width, y: height + 100.0),
        controlPoint:CGPoint(x: width + bendableOffset.horizontal, y: height * 0.5))
    path.addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: height + 100.0),
        controlPoint: CGPoint(x: width * 0.5, y: height + 100.0))
    path.addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
        controlPoint: CGPoint(x: bendableOffset.horizontal, y: height * 0.5))
    path.closePath()

    shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
}
```

Edit: It is definitely (im pretty sure) going to take more than just fiddling with this one method. I've tried everything I can think of, I need some new eyes!

Thanks you so much in advance - Please Help!

-Dan